# How to compute the dimension of cohomology groups?

Tags: representation-theory, group-cohomology

I would like to compute the dimension of $Z^1(\Gamma,V)$ and $B^1(\Gamma,V)$, where $\Gamma$ is a finitely generated group acting on a vector space $V$.
$$Z^1(\Gamma,V)=\{\gamma : \Gamma\to V,\ \gamma(gh)=\gamma(g)+g\cdot\gamma(h)\}\ \text{and}$$ $$B^1(\Gamma,V)=\{\gamma : \Gamma\to V,\ \exists v\in V,\gamma(g)=g\cdot v\}$$
If $\Gamma=F_n=<X>$ (the free group generated by $X=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$), as each $1$-cocycle is determined by its values on the generators $x_1,...,x_n$ then
$$Z^1(\Gamma,V)\cong V^X=\{\gamma : X\to V\}\cong V^n$$
Same for $B^1(\Gamma,V)$.

> > 1. Is this correct?
> > 2. How to compute the dimensions of these vector spaces in the case a finitely generated (not free) group $\Gamma$?

My motivations are from the study of the symplectic geometry of character varieties (the works by Goldman):

[The Symplectic Nature of Fundamental Groups of Surfaces](http://www.math.umd.edu/%7Ewmg/SymplecticNature.pdf)

Comment: To answer your question 2: you can't. Or rather, there is no "simple universal method" to do it. Computing cohomology groups is generally doable in reasonable cases, but it is a non-trivial operation.

Comment: @Captain, Thanks for your comment. I am looking for a textbook (or a nice survey paper) to understand the Zariski tangent space to $Hom(\Gamma,G)$, maybe using free Fox calculus. See [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09987v3).

Comment: I try to detail some examples. For $\Gamma=\pi_1(T^2)=\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $G$ is the $2$-dimensional affine group then $Hom(\Gamma,G)\cong\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\left(\mathbb{R}^*\times\mathbb{R}\right)^2,\ x_1x_4-x_2x_3+x_2-x_4=0\}$ is a (singular) $3$-manifold...what about $Z^1(\Gamma,V)$, $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ the Lie algebra of $G$?